# pfsense access openvpn client´s lan

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn, local-area-network, pfsense

I want to cover the following case:

- pfsense server´s LAN: 10.1.0.0/24
- openvpn client network: 10.2.0.0/24
- Local network of one openvpn client: 192.168.2.0/24

Working:

- Access the network 10.2.0.0/24 from the servers LAN
- Access the network 10.1.0.0/24 from an openvpn client

Not working:

- Access the network 192.168.2.0/24 from the server´s LAN
- Access the network 192.168.2.0/24 from any other openvpn client (except the one in this network)

I think this issue is caused by a missing route on pfsense.
So how can I define a static route to the network 192.168.2.0/24 over a openvpn client ip on pfsense?

Comment: Is the client a normal desktop PC (end user that isn't always connected to the VPN), or are you trying to setup a point-to-point VPN whereby the VPN connection remains static?

Comment: The client is a dd-wrt router, so it is connected always

Comment: Is the LAN behind a pfsense using the pfsense as default gw ? Or is it aware about the route to 192.168.2.0/24 ? Same question about "other" openvpn clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution:
The problem was, that I´m using virtio devices from my virtual kvm environment, but there seems to be a problem with the virtio networking drivers of virtio:
You have to disable the hardware checksum offloading in pfsense.

More information you can get here: https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/VirtIO_Driver_Support